# Error when setting the attribute on a styled component

Tags: styled-components

I get an "Object(...)(...).attrs is not a function" error when I try setting the attribute of a styled input component, like so

```
import styled from '@emotion/styled'

const DateInput = styled.input.attrs({ 
    type: 'date' 
  })`
    width: 360px;
    border: 1px solid #ccc;
    border-radius: 5px;
    height: 100%;
    padding: 0px 12px 0px 20px;
`
```

Any idea of what I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

.attrs() expects you to pass a function as an argument and you are passing an object.

You are passing this:

```
{ 
    type: 'date' 
}
```

It wants you to pass this:

```
() => ({ type: 'date' })
```

the completed code should look like this:

```
const DateInput = styled.input.attrs(() => ({ 
    type: 'date' 
  }))`
    width: 360px;
    border: 1px solid #ccc;
    border-radius: 5px;
    height: 100%;
    padding: 0px 12px 0px 20px;
`
```

Answer (score -1):

Use:

```
 import styled from "styled-components";
```

instead of:

```
 '@emotion/styled'
```